# Downloading and Installing the Nginx 1.23.4 version manually on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I am new to nginx. I want to install nginx version 1.23.4 and deploy my react application on nginx.

Currently, I have nginx **1.23.4** version downloaded. Then I followed the steps in this article and installed the nginx. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-from-source-on-linux/

Now nginx web server is working as below.

[image of web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esqen.png)

But, when I used `sudo systemctl status nginx` to check the current status of the Nginx service. I got an error as below in the terminal.

> Unit nginx.service could not be found.

And also when I tried to check installed version of nginx using this command in the terminal `nginx -v` I got the result as,

> Command 'nginx' not found

Is there any specific set of steps I should follow to ensure a correct installation of this version?

Answer (score 0):

For seeing the version use:

```
nginx --version
```

For status check use:

```
service nginx status
```